# Sharepoint 2007 _layouts/Upload.aspx does not open in my custom template

Tags: 2007, sharepoint-enterprise, branding

I've created custom template for Sharepoint 2007 by editing master page in _catalog/masterpage/defoult.master.
Every thing seems to be fine except upload.aspx form of my Library. When I hit upload button this file opens up in default SP 2007 template. 
Anyone know how to change that and make _layouts/Upload.aspx  open using my custom template? 
I can't modify anything in /_layouts/ as we are on corporate site.

Thanks
Evo

Answer (score 0):

This page inherits from Application.master, so you can change this file but itwill change everything *AND DOING SO WILL VOID YOUR WARRENTY*.

**However** there are ways around this, while not elegant.

You can make a **http handler** that alters the masterpage for every request. (Con: this may kill performance on a lower end server)

**or**

Create a **virtual layouts folder**, copy the base one to it, and then you can change the master page at will. (Con, you have to manully update the layouts folder copy you make from any future changes you make.

Comment: In my case any solution will do . In case it will kill performance I'll start thinking about something else. Would you be able please to provide more info on how to implement both solutions ? Especially the one with Virtual folder

Comment: There is a KB for that, here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/944105 http handlers are a generic aspx/iis thing so a quick google will bring that up.

Comment: thanks for the tip. I'll look into that . I was googling quite a lot . Maybe asking wrong questions ...